# Name of Theorem for Coloring of $\{1, \dots, n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integers, coloring, ramsey-theory

I recently remembered a theorem (I hope I state it correctly) saying that you can color a set of numbers $\{1, \dots, n\}$ with $2^{\sqrt{ \log_2 n}}$ different colors so that for any arithmetic progression, $a$, $a+b$, $a+2b$, ($a,b \in \{1, \dots, n\}$) has a different color.

I need to know the name of the theorem or at least the name of the person who proved it, but I can't find it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it. It's a theorem by Felix Behrend ([original paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1078964/pdf/pnas01693-0039.pdf)). In this [book on communication complexity (p. 54)](http://yehudayoff.net.technion.ac.il/files/2016/03/book.pdf), it's stated like this:

> One can color the set $[n]$ with $2^{O(
> \sqrt{
> \log n})}$
>   colors, such
>   that for any $a, b \in [n]$, if the numbers $a$, $a + b$, $a + 2b$ are all in $[n]$, they cannot have the same color.